# IIS, Websites and Embedding Applications

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications, application-pool

Im Setting up an IIS server (8.5) and looking at how to structure it. Its an internal business web server, not for customer hosting or anything.

My plan is to structure IIS as illustrated below.

Is this a viable way to structure IIS, by this I mean am I going to run into any disadvantages by embedding Applications within Applications within a single website? Or is it not recommended?

I will be using seperate App Pools for all applications. The root websites wont actually do anything other than group the Areas which hold Apps. In fact the Area (X) applications wont do anything either, agaion they just group applications neatly.

The actual applications will all be WCF web services.

- IIS

  - Business System 1 (Web Site)

    - Area 1 (App)

      - Application 1 (App)
      - Application 2 (App)
    - Area 2 (App)

      - Application 1 (App)
      - Application 2 (App)
  - Business System 2 (Web Site)

    - Area 1 (App)

      - Application 1 (App)
      - Application 2 (App)
    - Area 2 (App)

      - Application 1 (App)
      - Application 2 (App)

Answer (score 0):

Done some more research and it seems the general concenious is:

- Yes you can structure like I originally posted
- But.. I may run into issues in the future with embedding Apps in Apps

  - Such differiung .NET versions not being applied correctly
  - There are fixes but they are seem as a little 'dirty' so I'd like to avoid this

So.. I think I'll just use the following structure, very similar to original but I'll just use plain old folders/Virtual Directories within Root site to group true Applications:

- IIS

  - Business System 1 (Web Site)

    - Area 1 (Folder/Virtual Directory)

      - Application 1 (App) *Own App Pool
      - Application 2 (App) *Own App Pool
    - Area 2 (Folder/Virtual Directory)

      - Application 1 (App) *Own App Pool
      - Application 2 (App) *Own App Pool
  - Business System 2 (Web Site)

    - Area 1 (Folder/Virtual Directory)

      - Application 1 (App) *Own App Pool
      - Application 2 (App) *Own App Pool
    - Area 2 (Folder/Virtual Directory)

      - Application 1 (App) *Own App Pool
      - Application 2 (App) *Own App Pool